# why is there no quality selector for plyr in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, plyr.js

I am currently trying to use  [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) as a video player but i am running into an issue, i have multiple qualities but for some reason i am not able to switch as it doesnt even show me quality selector in the menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.8/plyr.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
        }

        #playerContainer {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #myPlayer {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }


        #backButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #backButton img {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="playerContainer">
        <video id="myPlayer" controls >
            <!-- Video sources and captions will be dynamically added here -->
        </video>
    </div>
    <a id="backButton" href="/wait">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='arrowback.png') }}" alt="Back">
    </a>
    <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.8/plyr.js"></script>
    <script>
        const timestampMovie = parseFloat('{{ timestamp }}');
        let title = '';

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const response = {{api_response|safe}};

            if (response.title != '' && response.title != undefined) {
                title = response.title;
            }

            if (
                response != undefined &&
                response.Qualities != undefined &&
                response.Qualities != null
            ) {
                const myPlayer = new Plyr('#myPlayer', {
                    title: title,
                    settings: ['captions', 'quality', 'speed', 'loop'],
                    
                    
                });

                makePlayer(myPlayer, response.Qualities, response.Srtfiles);

            }
        });

        function extractNumericSize(label) {
    if (!label) {
        console.log('no label');
        return label; 
    }

    const matches = label.match(/\d+/); 

    if (matches) {
        const numericSize = parseInt(matches[0], 10);

        const result = label.toLowerCase().includes('4k') ? 2160 : numericSize;

        console.log(`Label: ${label}, Numeric Size: ${numericSize}, Result: ${result}`);

        return result;
    }

    return label;
}






        function makePlayer(myPlayer, qualities, subtitles) {

            


            qualities.forEach((value, index) => {
                const track = document.createElement('source');
                const numericSize = extractNumericSize(value.quality);
                track.src = value.path;
                track.type="video/mp4"
                track.label=value.quality
                track.setAttribute('size', numericSize);
                myPlayer.media.appendChild(track);
            });


            subtitles.forEach((item, index) => {
                const track = document.createElement('track');
                track.kind = 'subtitles';
                track.label = item.caption;
                track.srclang = 'en'; 
                track.src = item.url;
                myPlayer.media.appendChild(track);
            });
        }


        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const backButton = document.getElementById('backButton');

            backButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const linkUrl = backButton.getAttribute('href');
                if (linkUrl) {
                    window.location.href = linkUrl;
                }
            });
        });


        const myPlayer = document.querySelector('#myPlayer');

        

        function sendTimestampUpdate(currentTimestamp) {
            const movieId = '{{ tmdb_id }}';
            const url = `/updatetime?id={{ user_id }}&mid=${movieId}&time=${currentTimestamp}&type=movie`;

            fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        console.log('Timestamp updated successfully');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to update timestamp');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error updating timestamp:', error);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an example api_response :

```
{
    "title": "The Dark Knight",
    "Qualities": [
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.360p.H264.20210201053642.mp4?KEY1=4gkezDFUitoN_kyLdEVgDw&KEY2=1709461546&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "360P"
        },
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.360p.H264.20190414191652.mp4?KEY1=EsIAiKAdqXz8OmsvJ81i9A&KEY2=1709461547&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "360P"
        },
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.720p.H264.20210201053642.mp4?KEY1=mnAp7Fx036WKv0RAmHNehw&KEY2=1709461546&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "720P"
        },
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.1080p.H264.20190414191652.mp4?KEY1=DcmI-5u4RH4sSHoNrDBQhg&KEY2=1709461547&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "720P"
        },
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.1080p.H264.20210201053642.mp4?KEY1=X3fye4M72jQyivvlcLrS1g&KEY2=1709461546&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "1080P"
        },
        {
            "path": "https://usa7.shegu.net/vip/p1/movie_mp4_h264/2008/4/6/4056/movie.4056.2008.4K.H264.20210201053642.mp4?KEY1=uNZKdm2bPlQgEELs0pAlLQ&KEY2=1709461546&KEY3=298116&KEY4=world&KEY7=23&KEY8=298116",
            "quality": "4K"
        }
    ],
    "Srtfiles": [
        {
            "caption": "English",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/751552/inf-tdk.EnglishHI.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Chinese",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306135/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.cht.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "German",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/986171/Subtitle.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "French",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306055/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY-FR.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Russian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/1146627/The.Dark.Knight.2008.Blu-Ray.RUS.SDH.full.voronine-1705263902.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Spanish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306128/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY-spa.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Arabic",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/780237/The.Dark.Knight.2008.UHD.BluRay.2160p.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.HEVC.REMUX-FraMeSToR.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Albanian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306082/Batman - The Dark Knight shqip.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Brazilian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/804386/Batman - The Dark Knight - 2008 DVDRip-XviD OpeD.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Bulgarian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/752848/inf-tdk.Bulgarian.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Chinese (Simplified)",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/509258/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.chs.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Chinese (Traditional)",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/509261/Batman The Dark Knight.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Croatian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/840962/inf-tdk.Croatian.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Czech",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306153/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.PROPER.DVDSCR.XViD-mVs-CD1.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Danish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306212/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.PROPER.DVDSCR.XviD-contempt.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Dutch",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/841230/The Dark Knight 2008 READNFO DVDSCREENER DVDR-The Batman.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Finnish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/936767/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.PROPER.DVDSCR.XviD-contempt.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Greek",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/756295/TheDarkKnight_2008_DVD-DoNE.CD1.EL.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Hebrew",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/973658/The.Dark.Knight.2008.BluRay.720p.DTS.x264.dxva-EuReKA.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Indonesian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/782646/The.Dark.Knight.2008.720p.BluRay.DTS.x264-ESiR.mkv.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Italian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/834815/dark_knight_ita_24fps.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Japanese",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/925207/The.Dark.Knight.720p.BluRay.x264-iNFAMOUS.tikal.JPN.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Korean",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306101/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.smi"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Malay",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/806391/The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.YIFY.Malay.Jkerr.Jk.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Persian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/811394/Assassin-s-Creed-2016.ALL.HDCAM.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Polish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/1100221/The.Dark.Knight.Polish-WWW.MY-SUBS.CO.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Portuguese",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/947290/BATMAN-The dark.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Portuguese (BR)",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/807022/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.PROPER.DVDSCR.XViD-mVs.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Romanian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306191/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Serbian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/812660/DKTS.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Slovak",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306069/Batman - The Dark Knight 2008.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Slovenian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/1118510/inf-tdk.Slovenian.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Swedish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/306094/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Thai",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/1128604/The.Dark.Knight.2008.720p.BluRay.x264-SiNNERS-1700043142.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Turkish",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/808829/inf-tdk.Turkish.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Ukrainian",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/1036579/The.Dark.Knight.2008.iT.WEB.uk-UA.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Vietnamese",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/843521/The.Dark.Knight.2008.720p.BDRip.XviD.AC3-ViSiON_Vietnamese.srt"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Xx",
            "url": "https://images.shegu.net/movie_box/movie/srt/4/6/4056/305999/Batman.The.Dark.Knight.2008.1080p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt"
        }
    ]
}
```

The reason I'm using plyr.io is because it seems to bypass CORS and it is needed for my sources. I am aware that plyr doesn't accept srt files and will fix that later, just need to get the quality selector working.